# How to connect SQLYOG to AWS RDS(not publically available)

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sqlyog, bastion-host, aws-rds-data-service

I want to connect sqlyog to my AWS RDS which is in private subnet and not publically available,there is limited solution and documentation available on internet regarding sqlyog integration with aws rds please do guide me ,its been 3 weeks i am working on this assignment

tried to access with bastion server ,which is in private subnet and network load balancer in public facing,

Comment: have you opened the port 3306 (mysql default port) on your security group?

Comment: @DiegoVelez yes its open

Comment: check these things 1: make sure outbound ports are also open. 2: make sure you have access to the RDS subnet, check routing tables.